# sigaction() with filled vs. empty sa_mask

Tags: signals

I'm updating someone else's old signal()-based SIGCHLD handling code and want to use the newer and better-defined sigaction() stuff which is unfamiliar to me. The old code fork()s children and wait()s for them in a SIGCHLD handler in a way which seems rather typical. Most code examples I see which demonstrate use of sigaction() in this context clear the sa_mask field of the sigaction struct via sigemptyset(). It seems to me that the safer move in general would be to do the opposite with sigfillset() to make sure the SIGCHLD handler is never interrupted by any other signals whatsoever. Am I missing something here? Is there some reason that your average child reaper would actually WANT to be interrupted by another signal (other than SIGCHLD, which I understand is still blocked regardless of the value of sa_mask)?

Thanks!